# $X,Y$ equipped with discrete topology $\implies$ any $f:X \to Y$ is continuous

Tags: calculus, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

My attempt:

Pick an open set $O \subseteq Y$ open in $Y$. So, $f^{-1}(O) \in X$. But since all elements of $X$ are open sets since $X$ enjoys the discrete topology, then $f^{-1}(O)$ must be open. Therefore, $f$ must be continuous.

Is this enough? or am I missing something? thanks for the feedback.

Comment: your explanation is fine. it wold be true even if you generalize it a bit : "If X equipped with discrete topology ⟹ any f:X→Y is continuous"

Comment: $f^{-1}(O) \subseteq X$, and not $f^{-1}(O) \in X$. Similarly the elements of $X$ are not open sets (you might want to say the elements of $\mathcal P(X)$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just $f^{-1}(O)$ is a subset of $X$ rather than element of $X$. And all subsets of $X$ are open, not the elements. Also note that you only used that $X$ has discrete topology. There can be any topology on $Y$. And there is dual version of the proposition where you take any topology on $X$ and indiscrete topology on $Y$.